# Como repetir número em um máximo?

Tags: c#, matemática, índices

Tenho dois inteiros: `n` e `m`:

- `n`: Número que irá repetir no índice;
- `m`: Máximo do índice.

O que preciso fazer é simples, é que seja retornado um número que seja `<= m` em base de `n`. Quando `n` for maior, ele irá repetir quantas vezes "saiu para fora" do máximo, por exemplo:

```
10 repete 10 = 10
5  repete 10 = 5
15 repete 10 = 5
30 repete 10 = 10
11 repete 10 = 0
```

> O mínimo é **0**.

Montei essa conta em C# para retornar de acordo com esses valores, mas não tive sucesso:

```
    static int Rotate(int n, int m) {
        if (n <= m) return n;
        int d = n / m;
        n -= d * m;
        return n - 1;
    }
```

E a saída do código acima, usando as mesmas expressões repetidas no exemplo acima foram, respectivamente:

```
10   -- correto
5    -- correto
4    -- errado
-1   -- errado
0    -- correto
```

Em outros termos, quando `n` é maior que `m`, ele volta para o índice `0` e vai indo até o que sobrar, repetindo se for maior que `m`:

```
15 repete 10:
m         = 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   0   1   2   4   5
n         = 1   2   3   4   5   5   6   7   8   9   10   11  12  13  14  15
resultado =                                                              ^^
```

Como crio uma função para repetir estes números neste índice máximo?

Comment: mas quando a repetição ira pausa? qual a condiçã de saida? Se não seu codigo ira bugar

Comment: Ela irá pausar quando acabar a repetição do índice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, é esta lógica que você quer:

**Obs.:** Fazendo como você especificou ("partindo do índice zero"), os valores não são iguais aos que você mostrou.
Veja que na sua pergunta, no seu último exemplo, você pulou o número 3 da variável `m` e duplicou o número 5 da variável `n`, o resultado, todavia, era pra ter sido outro, 4, ao invés de 5.

```
private static int Rotate(int n, int m)
{
    if(n <= m)
        return n;

    var auxM = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (auxM == m)
            auxM = 0;
        else
            auxM++;
    }

    return auxM;
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2rrCDW)